# Find a polynomial equation satisfied by $\phi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modules

I'm solving the following exercise from my class notes:

> Let $A=k[x^2,y^2]$ and let $M=k[x^2,xy,y^2]$ ($k$ a field). Show that $M$ is an $A$-module. Define $ \phi :M \to M$ by $\phi(m)=xym$. Find the polynomial equation satisfied by $\phi$.

I've proved that $M$ is an $A$-module but I don't have any idea to find required polynomial equation. Any ideas to find it?

Comment: Hint: What is $\phi^2$?